# Pycharm regex backreference replace error

Tags: regex, pycharm

I have mutliple init files in different files of the same format. I am trying to add a new parameter called "newparameter" for all of them. I am trying to use the find and replace regex feature of pycharm to do it but am unsuccessful so far.

I have an init function as follows (removed actual names of the parameter)

```
def __init__(self, param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7, param8=None):
```

Regex to find text: def __init__\(.*\)

Regex to replace text: def __init__($1, newparam="Default")

Finding the text works, its just that replacing doesn't work. The error I get is :
Replace Error. You have entered malformed replacement string 'def __init__($1,newparam="Default")'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$1` refers to the first capture group, but as it's written, your regex doesn't *have* any capture groups! In order to properly backreference, you need to capture a specific string in parenthesis.

Escaping the parenthesis with `\(` and `\)` means you can capture the literal characters, but also means you won't properly bind the reference to a capture group. Try this regex instead:

`def __init__\((.*)\)`

This will capture the content in the parameter list, also matching (without capturing) the parenthesis themselves.